# _ATL_DLL_IMPL is causing compilation errors in ATL headers

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, atl, winapi

I'm using VS2008 Standard Edition. A library is including atlcom.h and this is giving compile errors:

*This raises an error that `ClassesAllowedInStream` isn't known:*

```
struct ATL_PROPMAP_ENTRY
{
    LPCOLESTR szDesc;
    DISPID dispid;
    const CLSID* pclsidPropPage;
    const IID* piidDispatch;
    DWORD dwOffsetData;
    DWORD dwSizeData;
    VARTYPE vt;
#if !defined(_ATL_DLL_IMPL) && !defined(_ATL_DLL)
    ClassesAllowedInStream rgclsidAllowed;
    DWORD cclsidAllowed;
#endif
};
```

*Here, I get an error "**'ATL::CComVariant::ReadFromStream' : function does not take 4 arguments**"*

```
#if defined(_ATL_DLL_IMPL)
        hr = var.ReadFromStream(pStm, pMap[i].vt);
#else
        hr = var.ReadFromStream(pStm, pMap[i].vt, pMap[i].rgclsidAllowed, pMap[i].cclsidAllowed);
#endif
```

And looking at the relevant declaration (atlcomcli.h):

```
HRESULT ReadFromStream(_Inout_ IStream* pStream, VARTYPE vtExpected = VT_EMPTY);
```

My MFC/ATL headers are the standard installation from MSVC++ to the best of my knowledge, located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc. The 3rd-party library works for a large number of people and is well-tested, so I'm pretty sure my configuration is to blame in some way. It appears that for some reason `_ATL_DLL_IMPL` is not defined but it should be?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to change "Project Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Use of ATL" option to "Dynamic link to ATL".